# How to extract ALL hrefs from USDA_AMS web page using Python

Tags: python-3.x, url, web-scraping

I am trying to extract some urls from USDA AMS website to get some reports. Here is an example link:[AMS report_SlugID_3040](https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/viewReport/3040). I need the urls end with ".txt".

Here is the Python (Python3) code I am using:

```
Slug_ID = '3040'
url = 'https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/viewReport/' + Slug_ID
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
txt_urls = re.findall(b'href="(http[s]?://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/.*?)"', html)
```

It worked for several other reports (different Slug IDs) couple weeks ago, but not anymore. Don't know why.

Also I tried to use beautifulSoap find all the hrefs from the website.

```
web_r = requests.get(url)
tags = web_soup.findAll('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href', None))
```

It retrieved back with 43 links. None of them is the url I am looking for. I know there are some urls that I need when I do "Inspect". Such as:

```
...
<ul class = "section-data-month">
    <li> 
        MS_GR215, [04/07/2020], 04/07/2020 16:38:33, [
        <a href="https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/filerepo/sites/default/files/3040/2020-04-07/169146/ams_3040_00007_01.txt" target= "_blank">
        <span class = "text-uppercase">TXT</span>
        </a>]
     </li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
...
```

The urls I need look like: "https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/filerepo/sites/default/files/3040/2020-04-07/169146/ams_3040_00007_01.txt".

Could anyone help me? I am really a new guy in Python. Thanks so much!